# Is there a tool to convert RawLog to Carmen?

Tags: lidar, carmen, mobile-robot-toolkit

MRPT offers a tool to convert robotics log file from Carmen to RawLog. I need to convert the other way around from RawLog to Carmen but I don't seem to be able to find such a tool. Please, can you help me with that ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, sorry. MRPT only ships [`carmen2simplemap`](https://www.mrpt.org/list-of-mrpt-apps/applicationcarmen2simplemap/) and [`carmen2rawlog`](https://www.mrpt.org/list-of-mrpt-apps/applicationcarmen2rawlog/).

Note however that you have the possibility of exporting `.rawlog` files to TXT files (using either `RawLogViewer` or `rawlog-edit`), which may help you write a parser in the direction you need it.